# How do i return an array from php extension?

Tags: php, c, php-internals

How do I return an array from a php extension method? This is what I have so far:

```
struct myClass_object
{
    zend_object std;
    MyClass *myClassInstance;
};

PHP_METHOD(MyClass, getMyArray)
{
    zval *obj = getThis();
    MyClass *myClass = (myClass_object *) zend_object_store_get_object (obj TRMLS_CC)->myClassInstance;
    if (myClass != NULL)
    {
        int length = myClass->getMyArrayLength();
        int *myArray = myClass->getMyArray();
        // return myArray!
    }
    RETURN_NULL();
}
```

Comment: It's a PHP extension not a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After examining some php source files I was able to return an array like this:

```
PHP_METHOD(MyClass, getMyArray)
{
    zval *obj = getThis();
    MyClass *myClass = (myClass_object *) zend_object_store_get_object (obj TRMLS_CC)->myClassInstance;
    if (myClass != NULL)
    {
        int length = myClass->getMyArrayLength();
        int *myArray = myClass->getMyArray();
        array_init(return_value);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) add_index_long(return_value, i, myArray[i]);
        return;
    }
    RETURN_NULL();
}
```